# Installing Purpose

Tags: system-installation

My laptop is dell inspiron 15r, processor Intel core i3 HDD-500GB Ram - 4Gb can install Ubuntu any version and proper use this OS please help me.

Comment: yes, please check the link posted by @AvinashRaj, it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am having the same laptop.

Make sure to download 64 bit Ubuntu 13.04 or 13.10.

For more details on hardware system requirement [click here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

For wireless drivers and all click on Ubuntu Software Center and then edit ,click on preference and on tab addition Drivers as shown below -

[image]

Want to know more leave a comment with your question.